# Heating of metals in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

I'm thinking about how to calculate heating in a metallic object in a varying magnetic field. So far I have come across two laws which I think apply but I'm not quite sure as to how I would combine them.

Firstly, it seems to me that I would have to introduce the concept of magnetic flux:
$$
\epsilon = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}
$$

Where $\epsilon$ is the electromotive force, $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux and t is the time. My understanding is that practically, flux is $B\cdot A$ where $B$ is the field and $A$ is the area of the object.

Then, I think I would have to include the concept of Joule heating to determine temperature rise within the metal itself:

$$
P = \frac{V^2}{R} 
$$

Where P is power deposited, V is voltage and R is resistance. My first question arises here: can $\epsilon$ be substituted for V? Or is V different? Additionally, this doesn't seem to account for material properties at all. Is there a way to do so? I'm assuming a metal in air and water would heat differently (and different metals would also affect this).

Comment: This is called induction heating and iron foundries use it to melt metal routinely. If you search on *induction furnace* on google you will probably find what you need.

Comment: Hi @nielsnielsen, this looks like a slightly different process to me. Looking at the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating) suggests that induction heating is caused by eddy currents at the surface of a material, and is frequency dependant. Or have I perhaps missed a relation somewhere?

Comment: No, you are right, it's all about eddy currents and the bulk resistivity of the material being heated. Try searching on *induction cooktop* or *induction stove*.